# Validation no longer working after using a valueChangeListener

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

Hi guys i have some code where if a user selects the country to be the united kingdom then it displays the postcode field, this is working, however since i have added this i can no longer get the validator to work to validate the postcode is of the right layout and nor can i get the required = true to work either, this was all working fine before the valueChangeListener was added

here is the code :

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.country}" for="Countries" />
<p:selectOneMenu id="Countries" 
     value="#{bean.addressToCreate.country}"                                     
     valueChangeListener="#{country.countryLocaleCodeChanged}" 
     filter="true" 
     filterMatchMode="startsWith">
   <p:ajax update="postcodePanel" event="valueChange"/>
   <f:selectItems value="#{country.countryInMap}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:outputPanel id="postcodePanel">
  <p:outputLabel value="#{bundle.labelPostcode}" for="Postcode" />
  <p:inputText rendered="#{bean.addressToCreate.country=='United Kingdom'}" 
      id="Postcode" 
      validator="PostcodeValidator" 
      value="#{bean.addressToCreate.postcode}" 
      title="#{bundle.labelPostcode}" 
      required ="True"
      requiredMessage="#{bundle.requiredPostcode}" />
</p:outputPanel>
```

edit

country.countryLocaleCodeChanged

```
    package sws.control;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;

@ManagedBean(name = "country")
@SessionScoped
public class CountryBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Map<String, String> countries;

    private String localeCode = "United Kingdom"; //default value 

    static {
        countries = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        //countries.put("United Kingdom", "United Kingdom"); //label, value
        countries.put("Afghanistan", "  Afghanistan ");
        countries.put("Albania", "  Albania ");
        countries.put("Algeria", "  Algeria ");
        countries.put("Andorra", "  Andorra ");
        countries.put("Angola", "   Angola  ");
        countries.put("Antigua & Deps", "   Antigua & Deps  ");
        countries.put("Argentina", "    Argentina   ");
        countries.put("Armenia", "  Armenia ");
        countries.put("Australia", "    Australia   ");
        countries.put("Austria", "  Austria ");
        countries.put("Azerbaijan", "   Azerbaijan  ");
        countries.put("Bahamas", "  Bahamas ");
        countries.put("Bahrain", "  Bahrain ");
       countries.put("Tuvalu", "    Tuvalu  ");
        countries.put("Uganda", "   Uganda  ");
        countries.put("Ukraine", "  Ukraine ");
        countries.put("United Arab Emirates", " United Arab Emirates    ");
        countries.put("United Kingdom", "United Kingdom");
        countries.put("United States", "    United States   ");
        countries.put("Uruguay", "  Uruguay ");
        countries.put("Uzbekistan", "   Uzbekistan  ");
        countries.put("Vanuatu", "  Vanuatu ");
        countries.put("Vatican City", " Vatican City    ");
        countries.put("Venezuela", "    Venezuela   ");
        countries.put("Vietnam", "  Vietnam ");
        countries.put("Yemen", "    Yemen   ");
        countries.put("Zambia", "   Zambia  ");
        countries.put("Zimbabwe", " Zimbabwe    ");

    }

    public void countryLocaleCodeChanged(ValueChangeEvent e) {
        //assign new value to localeCode
        localeCode = e.getNewValue().toString();

    }

    public Map<String, String> getCountryInMap() {
        return this.countries;
    }

    public String getLocaleCode() {
        return localeCode;
    }

    public void setLocaleCode(String localeCode) {
        this.localeCode = localeCode;
    }

}
```

Comment: post the code inside your country.countryLocaleCodeChanged method

Comment: added in the edit above

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using `valueChangeListener` instead of the `listener` attribute of `p:ajax`?

Comment: Yes i need it to only change if the United Kingdom was selected using the selectOneMenu dropdown menu, only if this is selected should it show the postcode and without the user having to press any buttons and is it not defined in the p:select...

Comment: Then the listener will work just fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes i get the error it is not defined in `p:selectOneMenu`

Comment: That's because the [vld](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.4/primefaces-p/ajax.html) says `listener` is a attribute on `p:ajax`.

Comment: sorry i do not understand, could you please post an example ?

Comment: don't you get anything in the console log or a javascript error? Try adding a messages component. <p:messages globalOnly="true" />

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm no Primefaces expert, so this is a plain JSF-2 example of how I'd do this:

```
<h:form>
  <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.country}" for="Countries" />
  <h:selectOneMenu id="Countries" value="#{bean.addressToCreate.country}">
     <f:ajax render="postcodePanel" />
     <f:selectItems value="#{country.countryInMap}" />
  </h:selectOneMenu>

  <h:panelGroup id="postcodePanel">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.labelPostcode}" for="Postcode" />
    <h:inputText rendered="#{bean.addressToCreate.country == 'United Kingdom'}" 
        id="Postcode" 
        value="#{bean.addressToCreate.postcode}" 
        title="#{bundle.labelPostcode}" 
        required="true"
        requiredMessage="#{bundle.requiredPostcode}">
      <f:validator validatorId="PostcodeValidator" />
    </h:inputText>
    <h:message for="Postcode" />
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

The main thing here is the `<f:ajax>` tag which automatically fires a AJAX request when a `change` event happens. It then tells JSF to re-render the `postcodePanel`.

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove the `p:ajax` component.

2.In your `countryLocaleCodeChanged(ValueChangeEvent e)` method add the following code which will do the view update work.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance.update("yourFormId:yourPanelId:postcodePanel(write the component's relative path to UIViewRoot)");
```

3.Finally replace `required="True"` by `required="true"`

4.Optionally, you should add the rendered attribute to your `p:outputLabel` too so the  postcode label is hidden when there is no need.

Comment: I will remove the downvote if you explain the "why" behind 1) and 2). I'm not seeing how exactly it solves the concrete problem.

Comment: You are right ,  1) and 2) doesn't directly solve the problem but 3) probably does. Since he has a `ValueChangeEvent` listener there is no need for that ajax component as the only job it does is updating/re-rendering the outputPanel when the value of p:selectOneMenu is changed, but that job can done in the listener. We need 2) because of 1).